# want to protect views function from anonymous user using decorators

Tags: django, authentication

i have django website that require authentication and user login in order to use some functions and view templates.

i used the decorator **@login_required** but nothing is change and anyone still able to view html page and use any function.

what am i missing in my code ??

## views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
# Create your views here.

@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def create(request):
...
   return render(request,'blog/create.html')
```

## urls.py

```
"""ABdatabase URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

from blog.views import *
from .views import *
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings   


urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('',home),
    path("usr/logMeIn", logMeIn),
    path("usr/logMeOut", logMeOut),
    path('mainpage',mainpage,name="main"),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),

]
```

## blog.urls.py

```
# from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import *
# from django.conf.urls.static import static
# from django.conf import settings   

urlpatterns = [

    path('create/', create),
    path('list/', listANDsearch,name="list"),
    path('details/<int:pk>/',get_details,name= 'result'),# using <int:id> in order to display the id 

    path('listdd',homeInputlineBottom),



]
```

## settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for ABdatabase project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '5(%xarj8+c73-jmn*666gsmj1w5ix%vha8-c1vocevb=2#(()e'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ABdatabase.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                # 'blog.context_processors.home',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ABdatabase.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'canada'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS= [
                    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

even after i used the decorator nothing it change.

Comment: can you post your `urls.py` ?

Comment: Can you share your ```settings.py```?

Comment: are you logged in to the admin panel? check that. logout and then check the page again.

Comment: @Exprator i did logout from admin panel and still the anonymous is able to view the protected pages

Comment: @cagrias i did not change anything in the setting.py concerning the decorators.

Comment: the login url in the view is different from the one in the url file? should not that be /usr/logMeIn in the view? and where is the urls file of the blog?

Comment: @Exprator first i used this url  /usr/logMeIn and also it did not work. and i will add the urls for blog

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def create(request):
    user = request.user
    if not user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')    # Redirect whatever you want
```